# R Mann-Whitney-U test output like in SPSS

Tags: r, spss

I want to run Mann-Whitney-U test. But R's `wilcox.test(x~y, conf.int=TRUE)` does not give such statistics as **N**, **Mean Rank**, Sum of Ranks, Z-value for both factors. I need R to give as much information as SPSS does ([see here](https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/mann-whitney-u-test-using-spss-statistics-2.php))

I'm wondering whether I didn't select some options, or if there is a good package I could install?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In R, you need to calculate the various outputs of SPSS separately. For example, using `dplyr::summarise`:

```
library(dplyr)
mt_filt <- mtcars %>%
  filter(cyl > 4) %>%
  mutate(rank_mpg = rank(mpg))
mt_filt %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(n = n(),
            mean_rank_mpg = mean(rank_mpg),
            sum_rank_mpg = sum(rank_mpg))

# # A tibble: 2 × 4
#       cyl     n mean_rank_mpg sum_rank_mpg
#     <dbl> <int>         <dbl>        <dbl>
#   1     6     7          17.4          122
#   2     8    14          7.82          110

# Number in first group
n1 <- sum(as.integer(factor(mt_filt$cyl)) == 1)

wilcox.test(mpg ~ cyl, mt_filt) %>%
  with(data_frame(U = statistic, 
            W = statistic + n1 * (n1 + 1) / 2,
            Z = qnorm(p.value / 2),
            p = p.value))
# # A tibble: 1 × 4
#       U     W         Z           p
#   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1  93.5 121.5 -3.286879 0.001013045
```

#### Edit 2020-07-15

Thanks to @Paul for pointing out that the ranks need to be generated prior to grouping.

Comment: The statistic returned for the two-sample situation is actually labeled "W".

Comment: @42- but is equivalent to U in the Mann Whitney U test. There are differing definitions of W - see http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79843/is-the-w-statistic-output-by-wilcox-test-in-r-the-same-as-the-u-statistic

Comment: @42- Yes, but the original poster was asking about how to replicate SPSS output. In SPSS, the statistic in question is called `U`, and `W` is a different stat. I've now calculated `W` using `U + n * (n+1) / 2` where `n` is the number in the first group.

Comment: I'm not sure that was needed. My reading of the linked-to citation on CV.com suggested there should be no need to add that terms, but as always I do make many mistakes. (I was just trying to get people to look at the structure of the object returned.

Comment: I don't think it's needed either - it adds no particularly useful info. However, it was in the question!

Comment: I think `mean_rank_mpg` and `sum_rank_mpg` are incorrect. Ranking is done across all groups, so you need to `rank` before `group_by ... summarise`.